# how to install gdcm from sources in linux?

Tags: installation, gdcm

I can't find how to install gdcm, from sources, in Xubuntu. I've downloaded tha latest snapshot from gdcm, version 2.2.0.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcm/files/gdcm%202.x/GDCM%202.2.0/

It contains four folders:

> ```
> bin
> include
> lib
> share
> ```

Following official instructions here

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gdcm/index.php?title=Compilation#GNU.2FLinux

It says I should do this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install cmake g++
$ mkdir gdcm-build
$ cmake ../gdcm
$ make
```

But with the cmake command I get:

> CMake Error: The source directory "" does not appear to
>   contain CMakeLists.txt.

I don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would download and extract gdcm-2.2.0.tar.bz2

Comment: Then extract gdcm-2.2.0.tar.bz2 into a folder named gdcm. On the same level make the folder named gdcm-build and cd into that folder and run cmake ../gdcm